# RoR Returning 406 Not Acceptable, Requesting HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My issue is that I am getting a 406 not acceptable when trying to process the update action in a controller named "clients" (I am requesting HTML and am not processing JSON) my hunch is that I am missing something in the structure of my nested if statements because this only happens when validation FAILS for one of the nested processes listed below. I have been through my code and tried refactoring a couple of ways, but can not seem to get around this one. Hoping that a fresh set of eyes may see something I do not.

```
def update
@client = Client.find(params[:id])



respond_to do |format|
if params[:save_contact]
    format.html { redirect_to "/clients/#{@client.id}/edit#tabs-3", :notice => 'Contact Saved!' }
    format.mobile { render :action => "edit", :notice => 'Contact Saved' }
    format.json { head :ok }
else
end
if params[:save_job]
    format.html { redirect_to "/clients/#{@client.id}/edit#tabs-6", :notice => 'Job Saved!' }
    format.mobile { render :action => "edit", :notice => 'Job Saved' }
    format.json { head :ok }

else
end




if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
 @client.update_attribute(:branch_number, @client.branch.number)         

    if @client.wcrequested? && !@client.wcrequest_sent?
          @client.update_attribute(:wcstatus, "Pending")
          @client.update_attribute(:wcrequest_sent, "TRUE")
          @client.update_attribute(:wcresponse_sent, "FALSE")
          @client.update_attribute(:wcresponded, "FALSE")
          ClientsMailer.wcreq_recieved_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.wcreq_recieved_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.mobile { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { render :json => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }


    end

    if @client.wcstatus == "Denied"
           @client.update_attribute(:wcrequest_sent, "FALSE")
           @client.update_attribute(:wcrequested, "FALSE")
           ClientsMailer.wcreq_completed_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
           ClientsMailer.wcreq_completed_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
    else
    end

    if @client.wcresponded? && !@client.wcresponse_sent?
          @client.update_attribute(:wcresponse_sent, "TRUE")
          ClientsMailer.wcreq_completed_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.wcreq_completed_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
    else
    end

    if params[:gpreq]
          @client.update_attribute(:gpstatus, "Pending GP Approval")
          ClientsMailer.gpreq_recieved_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.gpreq_recieved_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
    else
    end
    if params[:gpreply]
          @client.update_attribute(:gpstatus, "GP Approval Completed")
          ClientsMailer.gpreq_completed_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.gpreq_completed_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
   else
   end

    if @client.cred_requested? && !@client.cred_req_sent?
          @client.update_attribute(:cred_req_sent, "TRUE")
          ClientsMailer.credreq_recieved_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.credreq_recieved_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
   else
   end
    if @client.cred_status == "Completed" && !@client.cred_rep_sent?
          @client.update_attribute(:cred_rep_sent, "TRUE")
          ClientsMailer.credreq_completed_corp(@client, current_user).deliver
          ClientsMailer.credreq_completed_branch(@client, current_user).deliver
  else
  end



      format.html { redirect_to edit_client_path(@client), :notice => 'Client was successfully updated!' }
      format.mobile { render :action => "edit", :notice => 'Client was successfully updated!' }
      format.json { head :ok }
      format.xml { render :action => "edit"}

else

      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.mobile { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { render :json => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.xml { render :action => "edit"}


end
end
   end
```

Comment: I reindented the code for readability.  Note that as @ksol remarked there were two `end`s at the end that didn't correspond to anything.  I'm assuming they were copy/paste leftovers.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. The `format` param is not like the other ones : rails uses the Accept Headers and the `:format` param to determine wether to respond with html, xml, json or something different. So I'd say you don't have support for all the formats you're trying to use, probably the `mobile` one is the cause.

Comment: That explains one of the `end`s, not the other one

Comment: one was for the controller the other was for respond_to do |format|

Comment: updated to reflect entire action... should have done that first

Comment: I actually had that thought too, commented out the mobile lines and still the issue persisted...

Answer (score 0):

406 errors are caused by the relevant format not being available or catered for.

I would suggest you start by paring down the action to just one respond_to block and move your business logic into your model.
Things like `@client.update_attribute(:wcstatus, "Pending")` should not be in the controller but in the model under a validation then just call the save method.

I suspect that you have a condition that is not being met with by your if else end statements. BTW else followed immediately by end is just plain wrong.

Anyway, cut it down and then see where that leaves yiu, then add the onditions back in one by one until you get the problem taking care to use the conditions to set local variables and keeping only one respond_to block that uses the local variables for redirection etc...